# Retriving value from Html to Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

There is my javascript and html code. I want to retrive data from javascript function to servlet. I tried below code but i don't know if its true. And also i want to get data html to servlet. Is there something wrong ? Because its not working ?

**Here is my jsp code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure about that ?");
            if (r == true) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('onay').value = myFunction();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript: myFunction()">
        <input type="hidden" id="onay" name="onay" />
    </body>

</html>
```

**My try to get data from jsp to servlet :**

EDIT:

```
int onay= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("onay"));
```

this code returns java.lang.NumberFormatException: null because i can't retrive data to servlet i think ?

Comment: you're not making any request to a servlet

Comment: Javascript you are using is only setting the value of input field. You have to submit it to the servlet. Put your textfield inside a form and submit it.

Comment: @Reimeus in jsp code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create form tag inside the body

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure about that ?");
            if (r == true) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('onay').value = myFunction();

    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript: myFunction()">
    <form name"frm1" id="frm1" action="servletname">
        <input type="hidden" id="onay" name="onay" />
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

then in your servlet

```
request.getParameter("onay")
```

without submit button you can use

```
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
```

or

```
document.frm1.action="servletname";
document.frm1.submit();
```

Comment: without submit button you can use

document.getElementById("frm1").submit();

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
        <head>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var r = confirm("Are you sure about that ?");
                if (r == true) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('onay').value = myFunction();
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="javascript: myFunction()">
<form action="servletname" method = "POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="onay" name="onay" />

//wrote a code for submit button. 

 </form>

 </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: actually i dont want to write a submit button i want to run it by itself when form loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't makes sense but,

try

```
<input type="hidden" id="onay" name="onay" value="myFunction()"/>
```

instead of this

```
<input type="hidden" id="onay" name="onay" />
```